# Blur in and fade out CSS animation, Two animations to one text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make an animation in CSS for text. When text appears it has to blur in and when it disappears it has to fade out, I can't combine these two animations together. I came up with two solutions but none of them are correct first(see code below) I made two separate animations but it is not synchronized and for the first time it works properly but when it runs again and again it desynchronizes and fades out while blurring in. The Second solution(see code below) is that I combine two animations into one @keyframes but it doesn't work properly too. Does anyone have any idea how to combine these two animations for one text? Is this possible without JS or I have to add a script if so, what should this script be? Set timeouts for each animation?

```css
/* FIRST SOLUTION */

body {
    background-color: black;
}
.animation {
    -webkit-animation: fadeOut 7s infinite;
    animation: fadeOut 7s infinite;
}
span {
    color: transparent;
    animation: blur 7s ease-in-out infinite;
    -webkit-animation: blur 7s ease-in-out infinite;
}
span:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
span:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
span:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
span:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: 1.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
span:nth-child(7) {
    animation-delay: 1.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
@keyframes blur {
    0% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    5% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    }
    15% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 0px #fff;
    }
    80% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 0px #fff;
    }
    85% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    95% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    }
    100% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blur {
    0% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    5% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    }
    15% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 0px #fff;
    }
    80% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 0px #fff;
    }
    85% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    95% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    }
    100% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
        opacity: 0.01;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    99% {
        opacity: 0.01;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="animation">
            <p>
                <span>It's</span>
                <span>all</span>
                <span>becoming</span>
                <span>clear</span>
                <span>to</span>
                <span>me</span>
                <span>now</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
/* SECOND SOLUTION */

body {
    background-color: black;
}
span {
    color: transparent;
    animation: blur 5s ease-in-out infinite;
    -webkit-animation: blur 5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
span:nth-child(1) {
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
span:nth-child(2) {
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
span:nth-child(3) {
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
span:nth-child(4) {
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
span:nth-child(5) {
    animation-delay: 0.9s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
span:nth-child(6) {
    animation-delay: 1.1s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
span:nth-child(7) {
    animation-delay: 1.3s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.3s;
}
@keyframes blur {
    0% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    5% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    }
    15% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 0px #fff;
    }
    40% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 0px #fff;
    }
    45% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    }
    70% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    90% {
        opacity: 0.01;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blur {
    0% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    5% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    }
    15% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 0px #fff;
    }
    40% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 0px #fff;
    }
    45% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #fff;
    }
    70% {
        text-shadow: 0 0 20px #fff;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    80% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    90% {
        opacity: 0.01;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="animation">
            <p>
                <span>It's</span>
                <span>all</span>
                <span>becoming</span>
                <span>clear</span>
                <span>to</span>
                <span>me</span>
                <span>now</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried combining them into one @keyframe? So that from 0 to 50% it does the blur, and from 50% to 100% it does the fadeout?

Comment: Hi, Yes i tried this and this does not work :/